# Visual Studio Code 32bit will not load Ubuntu Mate 17.10.1

Tags: ubuntu-mate, visual-studio-code

I am a neophyte Linux User, but experienced Windows (C#) developer who is trying to learn this platform.

I have Ubuntu Mate 17.10.1 installed on an older 32bit machine, and have added Visual Studio Code for the 32bit platform to that. (code_1.20.1-1518535974_i386.deb) I have installed it multiple times and ways, using both the command line, and the Ubuntu "GDebi Package Installer."

Visual Studio Code has been added to the Menu under Applications > Programming. When I try to instantiate the program, the VS Code Icon appears briefly on the Launcher Bar at the bottom-center of the screen, but after 2-3 seconds it disappears with no error message, and the GUI never appears.

I noted elsewhere the someone mentioned a log file that I could look for, but again, as a neophyte user of Linux, I have no idea where this log file lives.

Any direction for troubleshooting this will be greatly appreciated!

- damon

NEW INFO:
I have located the install folder /usr/share/code/ and in that folder see an executable (based on the properties) named "code." I also note that the Owner of that file is root with rw access, Group root is r, and Others have no access at all.

If I try to run the executable:
/usr/share/code/code

The result is -  update#setState idle

I am unsure what that is telling me.

If I try to run it as root (sudo su) I get the exact same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED:

The issue was/is that VS Code is indeed running, but will not display in the X2Go client.  When I attached a Keyboard, Mouse and Monitor to the previously headless Linux box, I found that numerous instances of VS Code were running on that machine, but were simply NOT displaying on the client desktop.

At this point, the solution was/is to punt X2Go in favor of X11VNC.  I am not as happy with this solution, but the driving force behind it is that, for using VS Code, X11VNC works whereas X2Go does not.